# problem with installation of elastic search on ec2 free tier

Tags: elasticsearch

this error occurred during 7.12.1 with OpenJDK 1.11 .  so i retried with lower version of elasticserach but it still did not work. i followed all the steps that is needed. but no luck

```
    got an error dpkg: error: 
ubuntu@ip-:/var/www/html/zoqolo_magento$ sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-7.12.1-amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 123297 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack elasticsearch-7.12.1-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking elasticsearch (7.12.1) over (7.12.1) ...
Setting up elasticsearch (7.12.1) ...
Exception in thread "main" SettingsException[Failed to load settings from [elasticsearch.yml]]; nested: JsonParseException[Duplicate field 'discovery.seed_hosts'
 at [Source: (sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream); line: 70, column: 21]];
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromStream(Settings.java:1102)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromPath(Settings.java:1075)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:72)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.createEnv(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.createEnv(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.KeyStoreCli.main(KeyStoreCli.java:32)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Duplicate field 'discovery.seed_hosts'
 at [Source: (sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream); line: 70, column: 21]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.JsonReadContext._checkDup(JsonReadContext.java:204)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.JsonReadContext.setCurrentName(JsonReadContext.java:198)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:399)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentParser.nextToken(JsonXContentParser.java:41)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.fromXContent(Settings.java:634)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.fromXContent(Settings.java:609)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings.access$400(Settings.java:71)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromStream(Settings.java:1098)
        ... 10 more
dpkg: error processing package elasticsearch (--install):
 installed elasticsearch package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 elasticsearch
```

this error occurred during 7.12.1 with OpenJDK 1.11 .  so i retried with lower version of elasticserach but it still did not work. i followed all the steps that is needed. but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st thing I did ie. I increased the swap spaces and decreased jvm heapsixze as per the memory capacity which is suggested in the documentation of magento2. thereafter I repeated the process then it is resolved now.

thx
sayantan